# How do I allow for straight jump and then coming back down to the ground pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, animation, pygame

There is a lot of code but most of it was necessary. It was named to attempt to be clear to understand. I am trying to get it to jump but when I hit space it only goes up a bit and stays there. I want to tap space and have it jump a considerable amount and land back with reasonable physics. If someone knows how to do this that would be really helpful. I am not sure about how you would do this with pygame.

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Inherited by any object in the game."""

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        # This makes a rectangle around the entity, used for anything
        # from collision to moving around.
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

class Duck(Entity):
    """
    Player controlled or AI controlled, main interaction with
    the game
    """

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super(Duck, self).__init__(x, y, width, height)
        self.image = duck

class Player(Duck):
    """The player controlled Duck"""


    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super(Player, self).__init__(x, y, width, height)

        # How many pixels the Player duck should move on a given frame.
        self.x_change = 0
        # How many pixels the spaceship should move each frame a key is pressed.
        self.x_dist = 5


    def MoveKeyDown(self, key):
        """Responds to a key-down event and moves accordingly"""
        if (key == pygame.K_LEFT or key == pygame.K_a):
            self.x_change += -self.x_dist
        elif (key == pygame.K_RIGHT or key == pygame.K_d):
            self.x_change += self.x_dist
        elif (key == pygame.K_SPACE):
            self.jump()
    def MoveKeyUp(self, key):
        """Responds to a key-up event and stops movement accordingly"""
        if (key == pygame.K_LEFT or key == pygame.K_a):
            self.x_change += self.x_dist
        elif (key == pygame.K_RIGHT or key == pygame.K_d):
            self.x_change += -self.x_dist
        elif (key == pygame.K_SPACE):
            self.jump()

    def jump(self):
        self.rect.y -= 3



    def update(self):
        """
        Moves the duck while ensuring it stays in bounds
        """
        # Moves it relative to its current location.
        self.rect.move_ip(self.x_change, 0)

        # If the duck moves off the screen, put it back on.
        if self.rect.x <= 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
        elif self.rect.x > window_width:
            self.rect.x = window_width



pygame.init()

FPS = 60  # frames per second setting
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

window_width = 1000
window_height = 600

# set up the window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Deterred Journey')

duck = pygame.image.load('walkingduck.png')
duck = pygame.transform.scale(duck, (160, 180))

player = Player(0, (window_height)-175, 120, 160) #Making player object(duck)

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(player)
while True:  # the main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #Closes game
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            player.MoveKeyUp(event.key)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            player.MoveKeyDown(event.key)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: If you want the player to jump, you need to apply gravity to the player object each frame. This can be as simple as adding a negative number to the player's position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple way to implement gravity to your game.
First, input a variable to control your speed. In this example it is `y_speed`.

```
y_speed = 0
```

Now, instead of

```
def jump(self):
    self.rect.y -= 3
```

use this code

```
def jump(self):
    y_speed = -3
While true:
    y_speed += 1
    self.rect.y +-= y_speed
```

This will make it so that when you jump, you always will fall, and just like real life, you might fall slightly faster. To ensure that you don't fall off the screen, implement some sort of collision detection, like this:

```
def jump(self):
    y_speed = -3
While true:
    y_speed += 1
    self.rect.y +-= y_speed
if self.rect.colliderect([some sort of object representing the ground].rect):
    y_speed = 0
```

This is a very simple way to do it, and I don't work with `Classes` very much, but this should hopefully help give you basic gravity and be able to be manipulated to work with your code.